# How can I create a method that I can access like a static class?

Tags: c#, xna, static-methods

I want to be able to create a method that I can call like a static class in my game so I can move the sprites for example:

**Code**

```
functions.move(Vector2Position)
```

The problem is that I can't use Instance Constructors in a static method. Is there any way of doing this or will I have to do something else?

**EDIT :**

I need to be able to call this outside the current class.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't use Instance Constructors in a static method"? You *can* use constructors (which are members of the instance-to-be) within static methods.

Comment: Perhaps you mean you can't use instance methods in a static method? That is normal, as static methods exist outside the confines of an object instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Static Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [Static Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on MSDN. In short:

You can declare a static class using the "static" keyword. This indicates that a class cannot be instantiated. Note that a static method can exist in normal classes too, not just ones marked "static".

```
static class MyClass
{
    private static int value;
    public static int GetValue() { return value; }
}
```

You can have a static constructor if you need to initialize the class in any way:

```
// Static constructor
static MyClass()
{
    value = 1;
}
```

You would then call the method with the code below. This could be done anywhere - within any other static or instance method.

```
int someValueSomewhere = MyClass.GetValue();
```